# How to set Visible all Value in rdlc grouping If data not available for that Group?

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have create One Rdlc Report File. I have used Matrix for display data. Also applied filter on Matrix for Date.

My data is Like

Date ,
Transaction Type = Inward Or Outward, 
Payment Type = Cash Or Card Or Cheque,
Amount

I have grouped data by Transaction Type in Column Grouping, and Date wise grouped in row Grouping.
Now the issue is When I am displaying data, If any of the Transaction Type is not available it doesn't display that group. But I want to display null value in that group if data not available.

How's that Possible?

Just Look at these images :

[!For Today Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9PJV.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9PJV.png)

[image: For Last Month]

Comment: How do you display a null?  A null is not visible it is a white space.  I think the problem is your JOIN statement.  You are not getting Outer Join which returns Joins when a null exists.

Comment: Look I have attached screen shots.